# Logging onto ROBLOX with cURL

Tags: php, curl, roblox

```
Remote Address:179.43.159.252:443
Request URL:https://www.roblox.com/home?nl=true
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: not putting cookie
Host:www.roblox.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://www.roblox.com/?logout=61253849
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
nl:true
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:164
Date:Sat, 20 Dec 2014 13:47:17 GMT
P3P:CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Refresh:0;URL=http://www.roblox.com/home?nl=true


Remote Address:179.43.159.252:443
Request URL:https://www.roblox.com/newlogin
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:34
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: not putting cookie
Host:www.roblox.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://www.roblox.com/?logout=61253849
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:userhere
password:passhere
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:130
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 20 Dec 2014 13:47:16 GMT
Location:/home?nl=true
P3P:CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Set-Cookie: not putting cookie
Set-Cookie:ChatWindows=; expires=Fri, 19-Dec-2014 13:47:17 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:IsMinimized=; expires=Fri, 19-Dec-2014 13:47:17 GMT; path=/
```

That is what my response was for the GET/POST request.

I'm trying to send a cross-domain request that logs me in.

No, this is not for malicious uses.

Please help.

Also, I have this code I was going to use:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.roblox.com/newlogin');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    username => 'USERHERE'
    password => 'PASSHERE'
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

One more thing, the remote address isn't mine. I'm connected to a VPN right now.

I really need help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging on to www.roblox.com with cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584931/logging-on-to-www-roblox-com-with-curl)

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing the anti request forgery token.

How to debug this:

1. Capture a site login with Fiddler
2. Capture your login with Fiddler
3. CTRL + W to compare what is being posted
4. Fix until identical